# why when i use the "required" with radio i always have the message error i have to choose at least one of them whereas is the case?

Tags: html, vue.js, validation

Whatever I choose i have the message error as if I had chosen none.

```
<form class="HandleUsers__form" action="" method="post" @submit.prevent="addAdmin">
  ...
    <div>
        <legend>?????</legend>
        <div>
            <input  type="radio" name="manager" value="manager" id="manager" v-model="role" required>
            <label for="manager">Manager</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="author" value="author" id="author" v-model="role" required>
            <label for="author">Author</label>
        </div>
    </div>
 
...
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezWZJ.png)

Comment: I think the problem is the "manager" and "author" input element bind the same variable 'role'. The "author" is not chosen so 'role' is not assigned any value, though the 'manager' seemed chosen. 'role' has been reassigned with no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because they have different `name` values, which creates two different [radio groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group).

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group.

Because your two inputs each have the same v-model but are in different groups, selecting a value for one group automatically deselects the value from the other group, generating your error since *both* groups are required.

Solution: If a user is meant to choose between Manager *OR* Author than they should be in the same group, i.e. they should have the same `name` value.

```html
<input type="radio" name="someGroup" value="manager" id="manager" v-model="role" required>
<input type="radio" name="someGroup" value="author" id="author" v-model="role" required>
```